# What does this line mean :/opt/glibc-2.14/etc$ sudo sh -c "echo '/usr/local/lib' >> ld.so.conf"

Tags: linux, shell

I had a problem while trying to [install glibc 2.14](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38317265/5407848), I got this error

> /home/myname/glibc_install/glibc-2.14/build/elf/ldconfig: Can't open configuration file /opt/glibc-2.14/etc/ld.so.conf: No such file or directory

The [fix](http://leistech.blogspot.com/2015/06/glibc-installation.html) suggested this

```
:/opt/glibc-2.14/etc$ sudo sh -c "echo '/opt/lib' >> ld.so.conf"
```

AFAIK `sudo sh -c "echo '/opt/lib' >> ld.so.conf"` means open the `sh` program(the shell) and give it this command `"echo '/opt/lib' >> ld.so.conf"` to execute, which creates a file  named `ld.so.conf` in the current directory and save in it `/opt/lib`, is that right ? what does the entire line means, or what the shell is going to do step by step ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking down the command: sudo sh -c "echo '/opt/lib' >> ld.so.conf" into bite size chunks:

`sudo sh -c` means to run shell command via the Bourne shell with super-user privileges.

`echo '/opt/lib' >> ld.so.conf` is going to APPEND whatever is inside the quotes + a \n (newline) char into ld.so.conf in the tail of the file.

Comment: Thank you, and what does `:/opt/glibc-2.14/etc$` mean ?, because it is the part that I don't understand.

Comment: That is just the person's terminal prompt output. Which varies from machine to machine depending on what is set for your environment's $PS1 variable. It is there before he starts typing anything, so it's superfluous to your issue and should be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Yes confusing) It looks like the first bit is the prompt (containing the working directory).

Therefore do

```
cd /opt/glibc-2.14/etc
sudo sh -c "echo '/opt/lib' >> ld.so.conf"
```

or

```
echo '/opt/lib' | sudo tee >/dev/null -a /opt/glibc-2.14/etc/ld.so.conf
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I will do that, if I didn't completely understand the line.

Comment: OMG, I'm sorry I didn't notice the first part *"It looks like the first bit is the prompt (containing the working directory)."* , this should be the answer I just didn't notice it, i'm sorry.